# Android: Demux MP4 into video and audio?

Tags: android, audio, video, ffmpeg, mp4parser

I need to demux an MP4 file into video and audio to do some editing on the audio. I don't want to use FFMPEG, I've already attempted to use it once and it went horribly. How would I go about demuxing? From google searches, it seems like there isn't even a way to do it. Nothing ever comes up. I was thinking of converting an MP4 into an MP3, editing that and then adding that audio onto the original MP4 using MP4Parser, how can I edit the MP3? Absolutely any help is appreciated, I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: What happened with ffmpeg, and what command did you use?

Comment: I never used it properly to begin with. I tried to follow tutorials to install it etc but no one explains it to a good standard. Once I had installed it (I think) I had no idea where to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will still find ffmpeg the easiest and best supported way to manipulate video.

There are good well supported wrappers that should address the issues you have seen - one example is:

- https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

Comment: Thank you, this makes FFMPEG much more understandable now